# How can I get a div just inside an input at 0% and 100%?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the @ symbol to be just inside the input at both 100% and 0%? https://jsfiddle.net/v6mcghdd/

HTML:

```
<div id="testContainer">
<div id="test2">@</div>
<input id="test3" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#testContainer{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#test2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  width: 0px;
}
#test3{
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: So you want the @ symbols to be just inside the input box at either end?

Comment: I don't believe you can, not cross browser.  The only way possible is to have a bunch of spaces (`&nbsp;`) between the `@` symbols.

Comment: @Alex Waters can you elaborate more about your question exactly what you want.?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/v6mcghdd/14/) what you want (hover over the input) - the transition is between `translateX(0%)` to  `translateX(100%)`

Comment: Yes, what @ZacBraddy wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the width of the '@' character this can be done with `calc()` together with `translateX`.

Assuming the '@' char is 15px wide:

1) Set it with a width of 100% of the container minus its own width (15px) `width: calc(100% - 15px);`

2) Now `translateX` will operate on it the way we want it to where at `translateX(0%)` the '@' is at the beginning of the input and at `translateX(100%)` the '@' is at the end.

3) Make sure to set `overflow:hidden` on the container

**In the demo below - hover over the input:**

```css
#testContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#testContainer:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
#testContainer:after {
  content: '@';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .4s;
}
#test3 {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testContainer">
  <input id="test3" />
</div>
```

Here's [another example demo](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/v6mcghdd/16/) using the same principle:

Comment: I think he knows that he can set `left` or `right` properties, however he wants to use a single percentage value to move the element within the confines of the input.

Comment: @GMchris I edited the post to what I think he needs now

Comment: Based on the question. I would never have guessed that this was what the OP was asking to do. It's cool though I like it.

Comment: This is really nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the before and after elements to it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="atBoxContainer">
  <input class="atBox" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.atBox {
  width: 500px;
}

.atBoxContainer:before, .atBoxContainer:after {
  content: '@';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.atBoxContainer:before {
  left: 10px;
}

.atBoxContainer:after {
  right: 22px;
}
```

Here's a pen for you to look at:
http://codepen.io/ozrevulsion/pen/KVOJwV

[EDIT] Just cleaned up the CSS a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code:

```
<div id="testContainer">
<input type="text" name="email" id="test01" value="@">
</div>
```

with this CSS style:

```
#testContainer{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#testContainer input{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The overlay is important so that I can move the div with javascript so that it actually matches the % position within the input. (it's a slider)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a negative margin?

```
#test2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  width: 0px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v6mcghdd/6/

Comment: If I set it to 0%, then it is outside the input. I need it to map the input from 0-100%

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want some sort of loading bar effect, where you just set the CSS as a percentage calculated in JavaScript. If so, consider the following.

```
element.style.left = 'calc(' + percentage + '% - ' percentage/5 + 'px)'
```

So if your `percentage` variable is say 80%, the above will result in `calc(80% - 16px)`. If you're unfamiliar with it, calc simply sets the element to a calculated value.

This solution works pretty well if a loading bar effect is indeed what you need. Since at 0%, it would display `calc(0% - 0)` and at 100% `calc(100% - 20px)`. Of course the actual amount of the pixels to subtract depends on how big your moving element is, but the principle is the same.

Can't really think of a pure CSS solution to this.